# conditional mean in discrete case

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I consider $$E[Y-E[Y|X]|X]$$ 
X,Y are random variables. Does the following hold for a fixed $X=x$

$$ E[Y-E[Y|X]|X] =  E[Y|X] - E[Y|X] $$

Therefore has $ E [E[Y|X]|X] = E[Y|X]$?

Comment: If by $E [E[Y\mid X]\mid X]$ you mean $E_{Y\mid X} [E_{Y\mid X}[Y\mid X]\mid X]$ then yes this is equal to $E_{Y\mid X}[Y\mid X]$ and your original expression is equal to $0$.  This is similar to saying that $E[Z-E[Z]]=E[Z]-E[Z]=0$

Comment: I don't actually know, what you mean with $E_{Y|X}....$  Can't I write that in my way? Why does  $ E [E[Y|X]|X] = E[Y|X]$ hold?

Comment: For essentially the same reason as $E[E[Z]]=E[Z]$

Comment: Thank you. I got it